# Injecting the Value of Dictionary into print formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting

How can I inject a value of a dictionary into a string using string interpolation in Python?

```
airports = {"key":"value"} 
message = f"{airports["key"]}" // this gives a syntax error
```

Using Python 3.7

Comment: any reason why you're not using `str.format` notation?

Comment: One way: `f"{airports['key']}"`.

Comment: With format(): `message = '{key}'.format(**airports)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes for strings,

```
airports = {"key":"value"} 
message = f'{airports["key"]}'
```

Another way to achieve this is,

```
airports = {"key":"value"}
valToPrint = airports["key"]
message = f'{valToPrint}'
```